vscode extension: There is no data provider registered that can provide view data
This is a simple webview vscode extension. I'm not able to get the extension to load the UI, and the extension only displays "There is no data provider registered that can provide view data.". not sure what's happening.
Thank you for taking a look folks!
extension.ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const myViewProvider = new MyViewProvider(context.extensionUri);
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(
      "view",
      myViewProvider
    )
  );
}

class MyViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {
  }

  public resolveWebviewView(
    webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
    _context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext,
    _token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ) {
    webviewView.webview.options = {
      enableScripts: true,
      localResourceRoots: [vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'src', 'webview')]
    };

    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);   
  }
}

package.json

{
  "contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "p",
          "title": "vs",
          "icon": "resources/icon.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "pagetok": [
        {
          "id": "view",
          "name": "vsss"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}


The webview should open after clicking on the extension icon.
